# What method should I use to normalise then average multiple readings for each variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalization, biostatistics

I am analysing the amount of fibrosis in tissue sections. Each section, representing an individual animal, has had images taken of it in several places and the fibrosis in those pictures has been quantified. i.e. there are multiple readings per n-number.

Problem:
Although each picture is the same size, the relevant area within each picture varies, so the fibrosis readout needs to be normalised to this area. I am struggling with how to do this, as two different methods give me different results, and I suspect they are measuring different things.

Method 1:
I take the sum of the total areas $\sum x$, and the sum of the fibrotic areas ($\sum y$, and divide the fibrotic area by the total area: $\sum y / \sum x$. 
I originally used this because it seems to observe the total area surveyed, and measures all the fibrosis in it.

Method 2:
Probably the more intuitive method. I divide the fibrotic area by the total area $y/x$), then take the average of all these: $\sum (y/x) / n$.
This seems more likely to give a picture of the average coverage of fibrosis on the section, as opposed to the total amount. ($n$ here indicates the number of pictures per animal, not the total number of animals in the group.)

Question: which of these methods is the correct one to use? Or, if they are both correct in their own way, how do they differ and how should I decide between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?Method&space;1&space;=&space;\sum{x}/\sum{y}&space;=&space;(x_1&space;+&space;x_2&space;+&space;..&space;+&space;x_n)/\sum{y}&space;=&space;\sum(y_1*(x_1/y_1)&space;+&space;y_2*(x_2/y_2)&space;+&space;..&space;+&space;y_n*(x_n/y_n))/\sum{y}]

more generally, [image]
or a weighted-average of % fibrosis area.

If w_i = 1 for all i, method 1 becomes method 2.

Thus, method1 gives more weight to the same percentage of fibrosis area if total area is higher. If you want that in you result, you go with method-1, if not, go with method-2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand. Method 1 gives more importance in the final average to measurements taken on a larger area? I think, then, this is the method I want to use to get the best estimation of the total injury in each organ. 
I guess I would use method 2 if i was looking at fibrosis in discrete organs that happened to vary in size, such as different muscles around the body, whereas here I am looking at different areas of the same continuous region  (the kidney, FYI) so taking the weighted mean is better.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Glad to have helped. If you think the answer is correct then please select it as an answer. Thanks